# Depth First Search Algorithm not working as expected when stimulating it with graphics.h C++ library

Tags: c++, depth-first-search, bgi

Thanks for looking into this, I was trying to make a visual simulation of Depth first search algorithm, using **graphics.h** in C++, Each of my graph nodes have 3 attributes, `x_coordinate` `y_coordinate` and a `nodeId`, also I have a separate Class for **Graph** Object which has the adjacentcy list graph, So As the following code was executed It gave The results as incomplete, one of the five edges in input ( Input given below ) edge **( 0 - 3 )** was not displayed [See snap shot here](https://github.com/pawan-nirpal-031/Advance_Data_StructuresLab/blob/master/betterdfs.jpg)  , can you help me with this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <graphics.h>
using namespace std;

int WINHEIGHT = 900;
int WINWIDTH = 1600;
void StartGraphics(int winx = WINWIDTH,int winy = WINHEIGHT){
    // int gd = DETECT,gm;
    // initgraph(&gd,&gm,NULL);
    initwindow(winx,winy);
}

class Node{
    public:
        int xpos;
        int ypos;
        int nodeId;
    Node(){
        xpos =0;
        ypos =0;
        nodeId =0;
    }
    Node(int x,int y , int nid){
        xpos = x;
        ypos = y;
        nodeId = nid;
    }

    Node* getNewNode(int x,int y,int nid){
        return new Node(x,y,nid);
    }

    int GetNodeId(Node* nd){
        return nd->nodeId;
    }

};

class Graph {
    private:


    public:
        int Nofnodes;
        int Nofedges;
        vector<pair<Node*,vector<Node*>>>graph;
        Graph(int n,int e){
            Nofnodes = n;
            Nofedges = e;
            graph.resize(n);
        }
        
        void FillCircle(int x,int y, int radius,int color = WHITE){
            circle(x,y,radius);
            fillellipse(x,y,radius,radius);
            
        }


        void Draw(Node* u,Node* v){
            FillCircle(u->xpos,u->ypos,20);
            setlinestyle(0, 0, 5); 
            line(u->xpos,u->ypos,v->xpos,v->ypos);
            FillCircle(v->xpos,v->ypos,20);
            delay(2000);
        }
        
        void CreateGraph(){
            for(int e =0;e<Nofedges;e++){
                int u,v;
                cin>>u>>v;
                int ux,uy,vx,vy;
                cin>>ux>>uy>>vx>>vy;
                Node U,V;
                graph[u].first = U.getNewNode(ux,uy,u);
                graph[v].first = V.getNewNode(vx,vy,v);
                graph[u].second.push_back(graph[v].first);
                graph[v].second.push_back(graph[u].first);
            }
        }

        void DepthFirstSearchUtil(vector<pair<Node*,vector<Node*>>>g,vector<bool>&vis,int cnode){
            if( not vis[cnode]){
                vis[cnode] =1;
                for(auto nb : g[cnode].second){
                    if( not vis[nb->nodeId]){
                        Draw(g[cnode].first,nb);
                        
                        DepthFirstSearchUtil(g,vis,nb->nodeId);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        void DepthFirstSearch(){
            vector<bool>vis(Nofnodes,0);
            for(int n =0;n<Nofnodes;n++){
                if(not vis[n]){
                   DepthFirstSearchUtil(graph,vis,n);
                }
            }
        }
};




int main(){
    
    int n,m;
    cin>>n>>m;
    Graph g(n,m);
    g.CreateGraph();
    
    
    StartGraphics();
    g.DepthFirstSearch();
    closegraph();
    return 0;
}
```

Nodes are 0 Indexed.

**Input** Format :
`Number of nodes` `Number of edges`

`Number of edges` Lines follow
`node1_id` `node2_id`
`node1_x_coordinate`  `node1_y_coordinate`
`node2_x_coordinate`  `node2_y_coordinate`

Test Input :

```
5 5
0 2 50 50 20 250
0 1 50 50 250 80
0 3 50 50 200 230 // Not displayed edge
2 3 20 250 200 230
3 4 200 230 170 300
```

Comment: You asked the same question previously and deleted it.  I will repeat my question -- there is no `graphics.h` in standard C++.  Where does it come from?

Comment: If you've read carefully both of them , they aren't actually the same the previous one didn't show any output at all , this one however does not show it fully, I am assuming you are not familiar with graphics.h it's a primitive graphics library for c/c++.   check here for more details  ```https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106b/cs106b.1126/materials/cppdoc/graphics.html ```

Comment: There is no such thing as `graphics.h` in standard C++.  *You* have to make it clear as to what it is, where it comes from, and what compiler supports it.  Contrary to what you may think, `graphics.h` could be anything anyone could have concocted, that's why you need to clarify what it is.

Comment: It is running here on my machine on windows 10 ```mingw``` c++ compiler

Comment: Indeed it is not a standard header file, It can be Installed from various  sources

Comment: *It can be Installed from various sources* -- And where is the object file that goes along with it?  It isn't just about a header file -- you need the actual library code at link time.  Those functions are not supported natively such as `initwindow`.

Comment: Is [this](https://winbgim.codecutter.org/) what graphics.h is about?

Comment: does it really matters how things were installed, I don't think so, please correct me if I am wrong,  But The issue seems to be with the algorithm. Also I installed it along with codeblocks and currently within vscode.

Comment: I am not exactly sure about it, but It doesn't look like it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie My problem exactly  is that it is not showing one of the highlighted edges in input (0-3) edge to be exact. While the other ones are displayed as they should be? I don't think the issue it technical though

Comment: First, vscode is not a compiler, it is a code editor that is able to run a compiler.  Second, it is important that you clarify the question -- if I were to take your code verbatim and plug it into Visual Studio, clang, etc. it will not compile, and if it did compile, would not link.  You mention `graphics.h` in your question, but you failed to appropriately apply all tags to the question, so that persons who know what `graphics.h` is could help..  Last, you mention the display not showing things -- if that is the issue, isn't it important someone has the capabilities of duplicating the issue?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I know what vs-code is, and what a compiler is, anyone who can write programs in 2020 knows what those mean, there is no graphics.h tag that can be embedded within tags section, I tried it.  I mentioned that one of the five edges is not being displayed did you really see the github screen shot link I gave with the question, also you don't seem to have read the question carefully and the code that followed, it is apparent from the questions you've posed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225524/discussion-between-pawan-nirpal-and-paulmckenzie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the (0-3) line never gets drawn because when you hit the condition `if( not vis[nb->nodeId]){` node 3 was already visited through line (0-2-3-4)

Comment: Ah , now I realize yes makes sense, so basically It's plotting the DFS traversal tree.